# UpdateVIew form data not getting prepopulated when form is used in Detials View

Tags: python, django, forms, view

[Base Update View details][1]
[1]: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/BaseUpdateView/

I am trying to have a Update form(updateview) in in my detailView template which updates one of the foreign key object of my detailview's object. I am getting output as expected and logics are working completely fine. I am using updateviewform as popup form but previous data is not getting prepopulated in the form.

Views.py file

```
class EducationUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Education
    form_class= EducationCreateForm

class PortfolioDetailedView(DetailView):
    model = Portfolio
    success_url = 'portfolio:index'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PortfolioDetailedView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['education_form'] = EducationCreateForm()
        return context
```

template
here portfolio is the detailsView object and education is its foreign key

```
{% for item in portfolio.education.all %}   <form method="POST" class="form-group" action="{%url 'portfolio:eduupdate' pk=item.pk %}"

    {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-row">
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
      </div>
      <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">   </form>
```

pasting this for an idea this is not complete code.

The only problem is data is not getting prepopulated into update view form

Comment: This makes perfect sense, since you need to pass the instance `EducationCreateForm(instance=self.object)`, but you can actually just use the `UpdateView`.

Comment: Since you here render multiple forms, you should take a look at a formset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I Completly got the concept of formset but the thing is i am using pop up form here...having a button in education display row.... Which popup a form to update that particular education row... In that data is not getting prepopulated...

Comment: For example you cn take linkedin profile education udpate button